# Number of rows obtained from an sql query from php

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php
// extract all the form fields and store them in variables
$WineType=$_POST['WineType'];
$Pairing=$_POST['Pairing'];
$PriceRange=$_POST['PriceRange'];

// the table will always have at three columns
$tablewidth = 600;

$sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM wine1";

  /* Set oracle user login and password info */
  $dbuser = "xxxx";  /* your login */
  $dbpass = "xxxx";  /* your password */
  $db = "SSID"; 
  $connect = oci_connect($dbuser, $dbpass, $db); 

  if (!$connect)  {
    echo "An error occurred connecting to the database"; 
    exit; 
  }

  /* build sql statement using form data */
  $query = $sqlstatement; 

  /* check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them */
  $stmt = oci_parse($connect, $query); 

echo "SQL: $query<br>";

  if(!$stmt)  {
    echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n"; 
    exit; 
  }
  oci_execute($stmt);


$howmany=0;
while(oci_fetch_array($stmt))  {
$howmany=$howmany+1;
}

echo "Number of items: $howmany<br>";
?>

  <?php
  oci_close($connect); 
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello, for the above code. I am trying to count the number of rows returned from an oracle server when i run the "SELECT * from wine1;" query.

It seems the the $count is zero after running the code

I have confirmed that I am able to retrieve all six items stored in the table when submitting the query in the SQL server itself. It just doesn't seem to work in php.

Comment: Have you tried assigning your `oci_fetch_array` to a variable and print_r the result to ensure it's not `NULL`. Also - is there any reason why you're not making use of `COUNT` in your SQL? e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wine`.

Comment: I'm actually building a dynamic webpage based on the search criteria submitted by a user. I'll have a go with the count method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in your case

```
$numrows = oci_fetch_all($stmt, $res);
echo 'Total rows: '.$numrows;
```

for iterating all records use this

```
foreach($res as $rows) { 
  var_dump($rows); 
}
```

Reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
int $mysqli_result->num_rows;
```

It returns the number of rows in the result set.

Reference - 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Oracle? MySQL? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your while loop like this

```
$howmany=0;
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
  $howmany=$howmany+1;
}
```

And there is an easy way to find total rows.

```
$howmany = oci_num_rows($stmt);
```

Hope this will help.